# InetAddress.isReachable only works when firewall is turned off

Tags: java, networking

I am using isReachable() method of InetAddress class, to verify whether particular IPAddress is reachable or not.

It is working fine when firewall is OFF, but why it is not functioning properly when I turned on firewall?
**Code is:**

```
InetAddress addr= InetAddress.getByName("192.168.100.5"); 
System.out.println(addr.isReachable(2000));
```

Comment: What does it mean "it is not functioning properly"??

Comment: It means in any condition(whether firewall is ON/OFF) it should return correct boolean value.

Comment: It is not clear, what do you mean. If you want to say, that when firewall is turned off `isRechable()` returns `false` - you should say exactly this.

Comment: I mean the same thing sir.

Comment: Which firewall? The one on your computer or the one on your router or the one on the computer you are tring to test with `isReachable()`?

Answer (score 3):

`isReachable()` does exactly the same as `ping` command, i.e. uses`ICMP` protocol. If your firewall blocks ICMP ping (and obviously `isReachable()`) does not work.

So, try the following. Turn firewall ON. Try ping. If it works `isReachable()` should work too. If it ping works but `isReachable()` does not ask another question with code snippet.

If ping does not work, configure your filrewall to accept ICMP.

Comment: I even created the inbound rule for PING i.e., ICMPv4. Then Ping is OK from cmd propmpt.<br/>But still isReachable() behavior is same i.e., it is returning false.

Comment: InetAddress addr= InetAddress.getByName("192.168.100.5");
 System.out.println(addr.isReachable(2000));

Comment: @svkvvenky, please avoid posting code as a comment. Please update your question instead. And the question is: does `ping 192.168.100.5` work?